# Can not find symbol in main AND Can not find symbol errors

Tags: java, netbeans

I have been working on an assignment for my first class in programming. I am working with NetBeans. I finished my project and it worked fine. I felt I could do better so I scraped it and started with a fresh slate. Now I am getting a message that says "No main class found" when i try to run it. But I have a main class. Here is some of the code:

```
package MyName;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MyName {
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    //declare new file
    java.io.File newFile = new java.io.File("LuisRamosp4.txt");

    //check to see if file exist, if it does then delete it
    if (newFile.exists()) {
        newFile.delete();
    }
    //used to create a file
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(newFile));

    //instance 1 of Guitar object   
    Guitar myGuitar = new Guitar();
```

On the this line there is an error message saying "Can not find symbol" only I have a class built already. here is the line:

```
Guitar myGuitar = new Guitar();
```

Here is a piece of my class:

```
public class Guitar {

boolean isPlaying = false;
boolean isTuned = false;
```

I understand i should have kept the code I had. I wanted to try again and now I am stuck. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What package is `Guitar` in?

Comment: Put a space between the closing parenthesis of main and the throws

Comment: I made a new class with it. But one of the files I had deleted had it as well. If I need to add a package, can you explain how I do it.

Comment: Just added the space and, nothing is different.

Comment: Where is the file `Guitar.class`?  Is it in the same folder / package?

Comment: I started a new project then went to file, new file and created it. I called it Guitar. So I think that will be the same folder.

Comment: Okay I started over again and the package is good now. I am not getting the symbol message anymore. Still have the first issue with the "no main class found".

Answer (score -1):

in java, you shouldn't use throws for the main method, it is already expected.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: This is the solution to the "no main class found" portion of the question.  The compiler can't find the main() method, since it has an unexpected definition, and therefore can't find the "main class".